# Does holding an action change your order in inititiative?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, initiative

I play in a group that has different levels of D&D experience from first time players to those that have been playing since the inception of D&D.
We are currently playing in 5th edition.
When we are in a combat setting, if a player holds their action in combat, they are told by the more experienced players their initiative changes to 0 and they now go last in initiative order for the remainder of combat.

Is this correct or is this a rule from a different edition?

Comment: Hey Josh, it seems you have created a second account. I've flagged this question for moderator attention so they can help you sort things out.

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) that way you can edit your question without it needing to go through review (+ the other boons of owning your own question)

Comment: But I have good reason to think you are the same person, so I've approved the edit, but I have a question about the wording "exoskeleton players", is this meant to be "experienced players"? Otherwise I'd really like to know what is meant :)

Comment: @NautArch I am not sure that the OP is clear enough on the distinction to be able to answer your comment, but we'll see.

Comment: Please let us know if those questions don't answer yours or what the difference may be and we can reopen if you are indeed asking something different. Duplicates are also more than okay here! We like different ways of asking so others can more easily find what they're looking for.